# Indenting issues

Tags: indentation

I am having issues indenting.

Below is my code/text:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\begin{document}
\newpage
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\begin{center}
  \chapter{Introduction}
\end{center}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em} \Indent A major feature of moral
psychology has been its focus on assessing moral judgments, with moral
judgments defined as an ``evaluation of the actions and character of
others'' (Avramova `I\&' Inbar, 2013). Taking influence from
philosophical questions, a typical design for moral judgment is to
present participants with a moral dilemma that involves choosing to
harm either one or many individuals. For example, a prevalent dilemma
used to study moral judgment is the trolley problem (Foot, 1967;
Thomson, 1986), in which a train conductor loses control of a train
that is hurtling towards five individuals repairing the track. A lone
individual is repairing the adjacent set of tracks. The conductor can
steer the trolley onto the adjacent tracks, but doing so would kill
the lone worker (Foot, 1967). Foot (1967) developed the problem the
query the difference between harm perpetrated with the direct
intention to inflict harm, compared to harm perpetrated as an
unintended effect of an act. Thomson (1975; 1985) followed with two
popular variants of the trolley problem. One variant is the \emph{Fat
  Man} in which pushing a fat individual over a footbridge is the only
way to stop the trolley (Thomson, 1975). The second variant is the
\emph{Bystander at the switch} in which a passerby comes upon the
scene and can divert the trolley towards the lone worker (Thomson,
1985). Findings suggest the act of switching the rails to adjacent
tracks in which one individual is killed to be more permissible than
pushing a man off a footbridge to stop the train (Hauser, Cushman,
Young, Jin, `I\&' Mikhail, 2007).
\end{document}
```

I would like to add an indent at the start of the paragraph so it reads:

```
     A major feature of moral psychology has been its focus on assessing moral
judgments, with moral judgments defined as.....
```

Oh, also I've read that LaTeX indents the first line automatically without requiring the `\setlength....\indent...` code. I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: don't do `\begin{center}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{center}` !! `\Indent` is not defined by default?

Comment: By default (following standard practice in many typographic disciplines) latex does not indent the first paragraph of each section. You can use the `indentfirst` package if you want  to indent such paragraphs

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When adding code to the question, it's a good idea to highlight it and hit ctrl + k (or use the code sample button, which is the one that looks like {}). This will add the proper highlighting and everything. It will also interpret spaces and line breaks in the question literally and print them in the output (hence why I used it for your example of how the paragraph should look). Stackexchange uses a markdown system and it actually works a little bit like TeX in some ways, for example, a single line break is treated as a space and multiple spaces are treated as one space

Comment: i've also taken the liberty of hard-wrapping your code for you so that it fits in the question horizontally and you don't have to scroll through. Otherwise, one paragraph with no hard line breaks in it will be treated as one massive long line, which you don't really want. Anyway, I'm a bit confused by `I\&' -- what does that mean and do you really want 'I&' ?

Comment: Hello @Au101 

The purpose of `I\&' is to add the ampersand & into the text. Without it LaTeX gives me errors

Comment: LaTeX will surely give you errors for just `&` but `\`I\&'` is very very bizarre, I don't know how it looks for you, but you just need `\&`

Comment: I also wondered what `I\&` was supposed to mean, although I left it in my answer

Comment: Hello. Thanks @Aug101 you are right. Works without the additional characters. I went literal with what LaTeX indicated I should use, which is why I added the quotation marks as well.

Comment: No problem, we're asking because we genuinely wanna know how you came up with that idea so we can help, because, well, I couldn't imagine where you got that from! In any case, I think you must have slightly misunderstood the error message you got, although I'm not quite sure what that error message would have been, perhaps it came through an editor, because the standard error message I get is `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.`

Comment: @Au101 type `h` to that error and read the help text.....

Comment: @werner well yes the question in the title  is a duplicate but it seemed worth answering to fix the other issues.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Agreed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh!! Tirefire, what that text means is that you should not edit your file and write, literally, `I\&' . What it means is that, there and then, in the Terminal, you should type I and then type \&. I is insert, it allows you to insert something at that point, one use only, and then \& is what you're inserting, so it's a way of editing the code on the fly to replace & with \&. This is a throwback to the days when compiling took ages, and starting all over again would have been a real nightmare.

Comment: If you put `\strut` directly before the text that you wish to indent, does it help? Under certain circumstances it works for me, but that's not the same situation as your question.

Comment: @RobtA what???, no.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I discovered that indent may not be able to "push" against text that uses `\smash`. Placing `\strut` in front works. Obvious why, in that case. Wasn't sure if there were other situations.

Comment: @RobtA a `\strut` is for controlling vertical space issues any effect on indentation is more or less accidental  but shouldn't really have \strut or \smash mid-document anyway:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah. I fix my bad code by adding more bad code. Thought it might work for someone else. Never mind.

Answer (score 6):

I added `indentfirst` and commented out some errors in the example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\begin{document}
% does nothing \newpage
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
% does nothing \setcounter{chapter}{0}
% no!\begin{center}
  \chapter{Introduction}
%no"\end{center}
% possible, but standard is already indented \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em} 
% undefined command \Indent 
A major feature of moral
psychology has been its focus on assessing moral judgments, with moral
judgments defined as an ``evaluation of the actions and character of
others'' (Avramova 
%`I\&'
\&
Inbar, 2013). Taking influence from
philosophical questions, a typical design for moral judgment is to
present participants with a moral dilemma that involves choosing to
harm either one or many individuals. For example, a prevalent dilemma
used to study moral judgment is the trolley problem (Foot, 1967;
Thomson, 1986), in which a train conductor loses control of a train
that is hurtling towards five individuals repairing the track. A lone
individual is repairing the adjacent set of tracks. The conductor can
steer the trolley onto the adjacent tracks, but doing so would kill
the lone worker (Foot, 1967). Foot (1967) developed the problem the
query the difference between harm perpetrated with the direct
intention to inflict harm, compared to harm perpetrated as an
unintended effect of an act. Thomson (1975; 1985) followed with two
popular variants of the trolley problem. One variant is the \emph{Fat
  Man} in which pushing a fat individual over a footbridge is the only
way to stop the trolley (Thomson, 1975). The second variant is the
\emph{Bystander at the switch} in which a passerby comes upon the
scene and can divert the trolley towards the lone worker (Thomson,
1985). Findings suggest the act of switching the rails to adjacent
tracks in which one individual is killed to be more permissible than
pushing a man off a footbridge to stop the train (Hauser, Cushman,
Young, Jin, 
%`I\&'
\&
Mikhail, 2007).
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am working on my thesis, and I open with

Comment: a quotation in my first sentence. I read, in writing a quotation, I start with two single `` and end with two single ''.

Comment: @Tirefire That much is correct, at least without loading extra passages. You should open quotes with \`\` and close with '' otherwise you will not get the correct curly quotes, you will have two "ninety-nines" as we would have said in primary school

Comment: @David Later on in my thesis I have to show tables and and figures and such. How do I turn off the Indentfirst package?

Comment: @Tirefire it doesn't really make sense to turn it on or off, the choice to indent the first paragraph of a section is a style choice independent of the document.  tables and figures are normally centred anyway so indentation isn't relevant.